# serve merged pdf (in byte[]) on servlet

Tags: java, apache, servlets

Here is the code including the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/2649430

I have 2 java classes. One is to merge multiple PDFs and return a byte array of the resulting merged PDF, then the other one is to serve the result PDF byte array on servlet. When I run the server, i get this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
    at testPackage.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)`

(A complete stack trace is included in the gist link)

Could you please help me figure out how to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**: trutheality points out that mergePDF() doesn't get called. so I updated the file TestServlet.java:

```
    public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static byte[] PDF;

    public static void mergePDF() {
        try {
            List pdfs = new ArrayList();
            pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("/test.pdf"));
            pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("/test2.pdf"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PDF = PDFMerger.concatPDFs(pdfs, output, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        mergePDF();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(PDF);

        // Set response headers
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(PDF.length);

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);

        os.flush();
        os.close();

    }
}
```

Still hasn't solved the problem:

```
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfTemplate
    testPackage.TestServlet.mergePDF(TestServlet.java:28)
    testPackage.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    testPackage.TestServlet.mergePDF(TestServlet.java:28)
    testPackage.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**UPDATE2**:

Thank you @mprabhat and @Zhanger, I downloaded the iText zip from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/) and put it in the project. It only provides me these jar: `itextpdf-5.2.1.jar, itextpdf-5.2.1-javadoc.jar, itextpdf-5.2.1-sources.jar, itextpdf-xtra-5.2.1.jar, itextpdf-xtra-5.2.1-javadoc.jar, itextpdf-xtra-5.2.1-sources.jar`

Does it look right to you?

Odd is if I write the merged PDF to a file instead of store it as a byte array, everything works fine...

Comment: `fix` what? explain your problem and post a minimal code here. Currently you have a `wall of code`.

Comment: Odds are `mergePDF()` doesn't get called before `doGet()`, `PDF` is `null`.

Comment: @trutheality OMG you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BINGO!

Thank you @Zhanger and @mprabhat, it's all the stupid RUNTIME path. So I solved this by putting the iText jars in `WEB-INF/lib` of the project. Works now!

Comment: In web application either your required jars be in the server path, or they should be in WEB-INF/lib folder, glad you found it working

Comment: i'm glad you found the fix! i would have never known, I don't have any experience with java web apps :(

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace is self explanatory, in your code you have

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(PDF);
```

as part of your `doGet` implementation, while you are passing the `byte[] PDF` it hasnt been initialized, its null hence the NPE.

Comment: In your web application lib folder the itext.jar isnt present

Comment: Have you worked with iText before? Could you please look at my UPDATE2?

Comment: sorry, I haven't worked with iText before, but browsing the [repo](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/) seems to show the class is indeed there, and it's basically saying it failed to find it, I'll see if I can find anything else :( although, [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/) link suggests there may be extra jars (oh woops commented on wrong answer)

Comment: @Zhanger thank you :) You're right it's there in the repo, but now you tell me I'm looking at the jars' content from the zip, it's not there!

Comment: well, one possible solution is to compile it from source yourself, but you should also probably submit some sort of report saying the class is missing EDIT: I just looked inside the jar myself, it seems to be there! see [here](http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/sagytoc2/Selection_016.png)

Comment: omg i'm giving up. actually I found it. and its exactly where it's supposed to be: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfTemplate

Answer (score 1):

as trutheality mentioned, it appears that `mergePDF()` never gets called, so you probably should place it in a [static initializer](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/06/static-initialization-blocks-their.html) (this way it doesn't get called every time a GET request is made and instead only once, increasing efficiency/page load times)

```
static {
     mergePDF();
}
```

in `HttpServlet`.

As for your other problem, it seems to be it can't find a required dependency. Perhaps check the .jars are in the right places/directories?

Comment: Thank you for your tip! Actually I downloaded the iText zip from the official website. I don't know why the some dependencies are missing

Comment: As the UPDATE2 mentioned, if I write the merged PDF to a file then everything works well...so I was sure that all the dependencies must be met...until now